# LEFT JOIN same table - Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, join, select, postgresql-9.2

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
  id       BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  company  CHARACTER VARYING(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  email    CHARACTER VARYING(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  city     CHARACTER VARYING(80),            
  postcode CHARACTER VARYING(20),
);
```

I got a list of cities and postcode. I need to find if any row matches with the data I have:

```
City,Zipcode
Lansdowne,2163
Villawood,2163
Smithfield,2164
```

I'm using this query; how can I achieve the expected result?

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.city,
    t1.company,
    t1.postcode
FROM 
    clients t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    clients t2 ON t2.city = t1.city
LEFT JOIN 
    clients t3 ON t3.postcode = t1.postcode
WHERE t2.city IN ('Lansdowne','Villawood','Smithfield',) 
AND t3.postcode IN ('2164','2163','2163',)
```

Would the query be right?

Comment: what wrong if exclude JOIN and leave only WHERE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would the query be right?

**No.** It would find any combination of given cities and postcodes (like  `('Smithfield', '2163')`. This Cartesian product would become increasingly expensive and nonsensical for more combinations in one query.

And the query itself is needlessly expensive and confusing on top of that. `LEFT JOIN` is misplaced and joins would not be needed.

The shortest, cleanest and fastest way to match on multiple *rows* (combination of multiple column values) is to join to a [**`VALUES`** expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html) (which is an ad-hoc table expression):

```
SELECT id, city, company, postcode
FROM   clients
JOIN  (
   VALUES
   ('Lansdowne' , '2163')
 , ('Villawood' , '2163')
 , ('Smithfield', '2164')
   ) v(city, postcode) USING (city, postcode);
```

For a big table, to make this fast, you should have an index on `(city, postcode)` or vice versa or at least an index with these two as leading columns.

Answer (score 1):

this query return data, but what the reason of this query if same result You can achieve without un-necessary JOINs?

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.city,
    t1.company,
    t1.postcode
FROM 
    clients t1 
WHERE t1.city IN ('Lansdowne','Villawood','Smithfield',) 
AND t1.postcode IN ('2164','2163','2163',)
```

this query same as original form not check City+Postcode (allow any combination), more strong form:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.city,
    t1.company,
    t1.postcode
FROM 
    clients t1 
WHERE (t1.city = 'Lansdowne' AND t1.postcode = '2164) OR (t1.city = 'Villawood' AND t1.postcode = '2163') OR (t1.city = 'Smithfield' AND t1.postcode = '2163')
```